# WMV Streaming of a DirectX render

Tags: video, streaming, directx

I've written a real-time visualisation app in DirectX.
The thing is, it should be displayed on multiple computers, as a videostream.

I'm guessing WMV will be the easiest codec to do it in, since it's MS and all that.

So, how would I convert a series of DirectX screengrabs to a fluent 30fps WMV video stream?

Comment: This is something I need to also.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you write a directshow source filter.  The source filter can supply an encoder with a series of bitmaps to be encoded in a compressed format for transport.  You can save this to disk with a file writer filter, or stream it using a network streaming filter.

However, this is a non trivial task!

Can we see your code for the visualisation app?  Please?!

Comment: I think a source filter is the right idea. There are examples in the Windows SDK you can use to get started. The constant transfer of image/texture data from the GPU to system memory (which you'll have to do to dump it to disk) is going to be a performance killer though. I would have a several render targets that the visualization renderer cycles through so that it's never writing to a render target that needs to be downloaded to system memory the same frame. Then you can have worker thread reading from this queue and sending the images to the the source filter.